# PHP how to extract string from the right side?

Tags: php, regex

Hi have this URL string which I need to extract possibly using regex but need to do it from the right side to left.  For example:

```
http://localhost/wpmu/testsite/files/2012/06/testimage.jpg
```

And I need to extract this part:

```
2012/06/testimage.jpg
```

How can this be done?  Thanks in advance...

UPDATE: since only the "files" in the URL is a constant, I would like to extract everything after "files".

Comment: There are several ways.  What is the exact logic you need to delimit what needs to be stripped off versus what stays?

Comment: you could use `explode` function and after that, use `sizeof( $array) - someValue` to get it as array items

Comment: I think the only thing that is constant here is "files"  so I am guessing I want to extract everything after the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
$string = 'http://localhost/wpmu/testsite/files/2012/06/testimage.jpg';
preg_match('/files\/(.+)\.(jpg|gif|png)/', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // Just the '2012/06/testimage.jpg' part
```

Comment: Thanks for that however I just updated the post and realize "files" was the only constant...so everything after files is what i need.

Comment: Just remove everything before `/files`. Updated my answer. The file extension check at the end of regex is a good way to ensure that you are actually only dealing with image URIs.

Comment: Sorry I left one / unescaped. Take a look at the modified code.

Answer (score 6):

You do not necessarily need to use regular expressions.

```
$str = 'http://localhost/wpmu/testsite/files/2012/06/testimage.jpg';
$result = substr( $str, strpos( $str, '/files/') + 7);
```

Comment: I guess this solution is probably a lot faster than regex.

Answer (score 2):

Use explode() and select the last 3 (or based on you logic) parts. No of parts can be determined by finding the no of elements

Answer (score 2):

This will get you everything after files:

```
$string = 'http://localhost/wpmu/testsite/files/2012/06/testimage.jpg';
preg_match('`files/(.*)`', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

**Update:**
But i think Doug Owings solution will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to check is this function i think:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

If "http://localhost/wpmu/testsite/files/" part is stable, then you know which part to get rid off.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing, it is not stable, so my question was asking from the right side...

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regex:

```
function getEndPath($url, $base) {
    return substr($url, strlen($base));
}
```

Also, a more general solution to return the end part of a url path by specifying a level:

```
/**
 * Get last n-level part(s) of url.
 *
 * @param string $url the url
 * @param int $level the last n links to return, with 1 returning the filename
 * @param string $delimiter the url delimiter
 * @return string the last n levels of the url path
 */ 
function getPath($url, $level, $delimiter = "/") {
    $pieces = explode($delimiter, $url);
    return implode($delimiter, array_slice($pieces, count($pieces) - $level));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the easy solution of explode (as suggest by knightrider):

```
$url="http://localhost/wpmu/testsite/files/2012/06/testimage.jpg";
function getPath($url,$segment){
          $_parts = explode('/',$url);

                  return join('/',array_slice($_parts,$segment));
}

echo getPath($url,-3)."\n";
```